# Adding elements to an JSON object in a external JSON file?

Tags: java, javascript

---

(After months of surfing the internet, talking to the school's computing department and try code out, I still don't get how to do it, but I do know more specific about what I trying to do)

---

Previously I said I want to "Add lines" to a existing JSON file.

What I want to do is simply add an element to an JSON object from a file, then save the file.
However I am still confused about how to do it.

The process I am guessing is to use ajax to load the content of the file (the JSON code in the file) into a variable then add the new element into the object then save the file.

I have seen a lot of code but are all just too confusing and looks like its for webpages. I am trying to edit a file on the computer as a program which I think webpage related code such as xmlhttp requests are irrelevant as the file is in a folder in appdata.

I have been confused and thought Java and Javascript were the same thing, I know now they're not.

What code or functions would I look for and how would it be used in the code?

(Please don't post pseudocode because I have no idea how to write the code for them since I have literally no idea how to code anything other than a html webpage and some php. Other coding language like Java, Javascript and Python I have little knowledge with but not enough to write a program alone.)

Comment: The specified JSON file contains syntax error: the value of "profile" is array (declared with [...]), but contains key-value pairs, as it would be object. Fix: replace [] with {}.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to use code that somebody else has already written to manipulate the JSON. There are plenty of libraries for that, and the best would be the officially specified one, [JSON-P](https://jsonp.java.net). What you would do is this:

1. Go to http://jsonp.java.net/ and download JSON-P. (You will have to examine the page carefully to find the link to "[JSON Processing RI jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.jar)".) You will need to include this JAR in your class path while you write your program.
2. Add imports to your program for `javax.json.*`.
3. Write this code to do the job (you will have to catch `JsonException`s and `IOException`s):

   ```
   JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new FileReader("launcher_profiles.json"));
   JsonObject file = reader.readObject();
   reader.close();
   JsonObject profiles = file.getJsonObject("profiles");
   JsonObject newProfile = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                               .add("name", "New Lines")
                               .add("gameDir", "New Lines")
                               .add("lastVersionId", "New Lines")
                               .add("playerUUID", "")
                           .build();
   JsonObjectBuilder objectBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                       .add("New Profile Name", newProfile);
   for (java.util.Map.Entry<String, JsonValue> entry : profiles.entrySet())
       objectBuilder.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
   JsonObject newProfiles = objectBuilder.build();

   // Now, figure out what I have done so far and write the rest of the code yourself! At the end, use this code to write out the new file:
   JsonWriter writer = Json.createWriter(new FileWriter("launcher_profiles.json"));
   writer.writeObject(newFile);
   writer.close();
   ```

Comment: Solution is good, but could be enhanced a little bit: 1) instead of downloading jar, better use maven or gradle to manage dependencies. JSON-API implementation is available under coordinates 'org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4'. 2) "close" operations should be placed to try-finally blocks to guarantee resource cleanup.

Comment: I read the code several times and understood it until "JsonObjectBuilder objectBuilder..." to the end of the "for" statement. Can you explain what it does please?

Also, from this it looks like this script file will need to be in the same folder as the '.json'. If it is under another directory, will I just add the directory path in the "FileReader()" and the "FileWriter()"?

Comment: "Can you explain what it does please?" I will add comments to the code. Re: the file paths for the JSON file, it will only work if the current directory when the program is run contains `launcher_profile.json`. To change that, yes, you just have to change the file paths in the `FileReader` and `FileWriter` constructors.

Comment: I am guessing this won't work on a .js file written in notepad? Is this right? (The entire script, because I am getting syntax errors on import).

Comment: Sorry, I just can't get it to work. On a .js file saved by Notepad++ get import errors. When I used Eclipse the Importing works but the code gave me some errors that I have no clue how to fix. The .java file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85468905/StackOverflow/Main.java

Comment: You may have not noticed this line: `// Now, figure out what I have done so far and write the rest of the code yourself! At the end, use this code to write out the new file:` As for the rest of the errors, I have edited the code to fix them.

Comment: Sorry, call me stupid, but I have tried everything I could find, but no results. Also, I get very confused when using libraries. My apologies.

Comment: If all you want to do is change your JSON file a little bit, try [JSON Editor Online](http://jsoneditoronline.org). Paste your JSON into the left half of the window, click the right-pointing arrow in the middle, make some changes, and click Save. It will download a new JSON file which you can substitute for the original.